# Timeout in Excel, executes immediately in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba, vb6, ado

I have a strange problem in excel with an `ADODB.Connection/Recordset`. I must admit that i'm not that familiar with VBA/VB6 and ADO.

I'm using a function in an excel-addin to return a price from a column in SQL-Server. Therefore i'm calling a scalar-valued-function. This function takes three parameters, only the first is mandatory. If i provide a second (`datetime`) parameter i get a timout error.

Here's the complete function although i assume that it's not relevant:

```
Const connStr As String = "Connection-String"
Private conn As ADODB.Connection

Public Function GetClaimPriceByPartNumber(partNumber As String, Optional claimSubmittedDateEnd As String = "", Optional currencyName As String = "EUR") As String
    If conn Is Nothing Then
        Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
        conn.ConnectionString = connStr
    End If

    If conn.State <> 1 Then conn.Open

    If Trim(currencyName) = "" Then
        currencyName = "EUR"
    End If

    If Trim(claimSubmittedDateEnd) = "" Then
        claimSubmittedDateEnd = "NULL"
    Else
        claimSubmittedDateEnd = "CONVERT(DATETIME, '" & SQLDate(claimSubmittedDateEnd) & "', 102)"
    End If

    Dim str As String
    str = "SELECT COALESCE([dbo].[_GetClaimPriceByPartNumber]('" & partNumber & "'," & claimSubmittedDateEnd & ",'" & currencyName & "'),-1)As Price"
    ' even a static datetime does not work: CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-11-11', 102)  '
    On Error GoTo Exception
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    rs.Open str, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
    On Error GoTo Exception

    If rs.EOF Then
        GetClaimPriceByPartNumber = "part not claimed or no price found"
    Else
        Dim price As Double
        price = rs!price
        If price < 0 Then
            GetClaimPriceByPartNumber = "N/A"
        Else
            GetClaimPriceByPartNumber = Round(price, 2)
        End If
    End If

Escape:
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        If rs.State = adStateOpen Then rs.Close
    End If
    Exit Function

Exception:
    GetClaimPriceByPartNumber = Err.Description
End Function
```

I cannot reproduce this timeout in sql-server. I haved used the profiler to see what sql is used. But even this returns the result immediately in SSMS:

```
declare @p1 int
set @p1=NULL
declare @p3 int
set @p3=557064
declare @p4 int
set @p4=98305
declare @p5 int
set @p5=NULL
exec sp_cursoropen @p1 output,N'SELECT COALESCE([dbo].[_GetClaimPriceByPartNumber](''1271-4303'',CONVERT(DATETIME, ''2013-11-11'', 102),''EUR''),-1)As Price',@p3 output,@p4 output,@p5 output
select @p1, @p3, @p4, @p5
```

I can post `_GetClaimPriceByPartNumber` if you think that it's important.

I am at my wit's end. Maybe you have an idea what's going on or what i can try/improve.

Comment: does your sql string come out as you would expect? `Debug.Print str`

Comment: @Sam: yes, it's `SELECT COALESCE([dbo].[_GetClaimPriceByPartNumber]('1271-4303',CONVERT(DATETIME, '2013-11-11', 102),'EUR'),-1)As Price` as desired and it works without a problem in SSMS. If i replace the `datetime` parameter with `NULL` it also executes immediately. Note that the exception is raised at the line which starts with `rs.Open str`.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with ADO myself, but I know a little about VBA.. Two things; `price = rs!price` doesn't look right to me. And have you tried temporarily swapping out your query for something simpler so you know if the problem is with the VB code / connection or the function.

Comment: @Sam: Thanks. Actually this is inherited from legacy code from someone who knows a lot about ADO. As i've learned the exclamation mark is a [operator to access a dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712034%28VS.71%29.aspx)(as the recordset in this case, `price` is the alias for the result).
The exception is also raised earlier as soon as the [connection is opened](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675544(v=vs.85).aspx). As i've mentioned, the function works if i remove the second datetime parameter since that's optional (in sql-server).

Comment: Thanks (I've learned something new today). Only other thing I may suggest is that you format your date in VB and pass the formatted string rather than passing the value into the `CONVERT` function. `Format` or `Application.Text` functions can be used for date formatting. Other than that, I'm out of ideas..  Good luck.

Comment: @Sam: I don't know why and i normally avoid to send wrong types, but your suggestion to use the datetime as text works if i let the function convert it. So if you post it as answer i would accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: I added my comment as an answer Tim. Will you accept it please?

Comment: @Sam: Sorry, I forgot about it. Note that i've just passed the date as string to the function. The conversion is done there. It works immediately. Maybe a sql-server optimizer issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than converting the Date by using the `CONVERT` function

```
 claimSubmittedDateEnd = "CONVERT(DATETIME, '" & SQLDate(claimSubmittedDateEnd) & "', 102)"
```

Try passing the value as text to the function and letting it handle the conversion. `Application.Text` or `Format` can be used to format dates as strings in VBA.